# 'An error was encountered while retrieving the status for the selected map' error in sitecore 8.1 update 2 path analyzer

Tags: sitecore

'**An error was encountered while retrieving the status for the selected map**' error in sitecore 8.1 update 2 path analyzer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this issue on https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/9/t/3781

but it did not work for me.
I further investigated and found that the issue was due to permission on account with which I logged in.
When I logged in with admin account, it worked fine.